# How to stop the animation when audio is stopped with onclick using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I have an issue to stopped animation when audio is paused. Basically, When page is load, then when I click in div then music started playing with animation but when I click this div again to pause the music, then music was paused but animation was not stopped.Can Any one help me please?

Html Code

```
<audio id="track" autoplay loop>
  <source src="video/dw_svends_awakening_music.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
<div class="bar-c play" id="sound_button">
  <div id="bar-1" class="bar"></div>
  <div id="bar-2" class="bar"></div>
  <div id="bar-3" class="bar"></div>
  <div id="bar-4" class="bar"></div>
  <div id="bar-5" class="bar"></div>
  <div id="bar-6" class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

style.css

```
.bar.noAnim {
    -webkit-animation: none;
    animation: none;
    -webkit-animation-name: none;
    animation-name: none;
}
```

javascript code

```
function playPause() {
  if (track.paused) {
    track.play();
    //controlBtn.textContent = "Pause";
    controlBtn.className = "play";
  } else {
    track.pause();
    //controlBtn.textContent = "Play";
    controlBtn.className = "pause";
  }
}

controlBtn.addEventListener("click", playPause);

track.addEventListener("ended", function() {
  controlBtn.className = "play";
});

$("#sound_button").click(function() {
  $(".bar").toggleClass("noAnim");  
});
```

Comment: `controlBtn.classList.add()`, `controlBtn.classList.remove()`

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava Thanks for ur reply. I tried this but not working..

Comment: I have just edited my JavaScript code. Can u please check this and hlep.Thanks

Comment: Why use both jQuery and standard JS for the same kind of things? Having said that, try turning this into a [mcve] because there's some code missing at the moment to make this actually work the way you're describing.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Can u please help me? Thanks

Comment: [help us help you](/help/how-to-ask) instead of asking whether someone can help you in the comments: that's the whole point of Stackoverflow, just post a question that lets people post answers, and you'll get answers. In fact, someone already gave you some solid advice on how to make sure your functions trigger at the right time.

Answer (score 0):

You should properly track when the audio element is playing or not by [listening to its events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement).

```
const audio = document.querySelector('audio');
audio.addEventListener('play', (e) => {
  controlBtn.classList.add('playing');
});
audio.addEventListener('pause', (e) => {
  controlBtn.classListe.remove('playing');
});
```